# SAPUI5 jQuery.sap.storage variable saving

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, sapui5

In my application I have a function for a synchronisation in which I take two timestamps, at the start and the end, to get the time spent while synchronizing.

I want to save this variable into the local storage.

After that I need to compare the variable coming from the function with the variable from the function and get the average of them.

I know the storage is a key-value type, I still have problems getting this work. The function is posted below. Thanks for every possible help.

```
handleSyncPress: function() {

    new Date().getTime();
    var syncStart = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    var that = this;
    var fUpdateBindings = function() {
        that.getView().getModel().refresh(true);
    }
    test.mp.Offline.sync(fUpdateBindings);

    new Date().getTime();
    var syncEnd = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    var syncTime = syncEnd - syncStart;
    this._oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
    this._oMyData = this._oStorage.get(syncTime);
    this._oStorage.put(syncTime, this._oMyData);
}
```

As you can see I'll started the initialisation of the storage already at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment in your other question, the storage is something like a dictionary that stores key-value-pairs.

The key is the identifier that you will use to access your value later.

The value can be anything: Numbers, Strings, Bools, Arrays, Objects, you name it.

Imo the best solution would be to store all your sync times in a single value (i. e. an array of sync times).

```
handleSyncPress: function() {
    // get current timestamp
    var syncStart = Date.now();

    // do stuff
    var fUpdateBindings = function() {
        that.getView().getModel().refresh(true);
    }

    test.mp.Offline.sync(fUpdateBindings);

    // get another timestamp
    var syncEnd = Date.now();
    // diff between the timestamps is the sync time (in milliseconds)
    var syncTimeInMilliseconds = syncEnd - syncStart;

    this._oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
    // load value for the key "syncTimes"
    var aSyncTimes = this._oStorage.get("syncTimes");
    aSyncTimes = JSON.parse(aSyncTimes); // may not be needed
    // if this is the first time you access the key, initialize the value
    if (aSyncTimes === null) {
        aSyncTimes = [];
    }
    // append your new sync time
    aSyncTimes.push(syncTimeInMilliseconds);
    // store your sync time array
    aSyncTimes = JSON.stringify(aSyncTimes); // may not be needed
    this._oStorage.put("syncTimes", aSyncTimes);

    // hopefully you already know how to calculate the avg value from an array of integers
    // if not: avg = sum / length
}
```

---

**Edit:** According to the API, only strings are supported as values. I tried other types, and they worked, but it might be safest to (de)serialize the data. I updated the code example.

Comment: Once again my question was badly put. I knew you were right yesterday and it worked, the problem was:

I was not allowed to use the array as the memory would run full.

So in the End I had to work with one variable in the storage.

The mistake in the end was a typo. I would have deleted the question, but that was no longer possible.

Comment: The only question I have left If I can use the storage in another View.XML from my JavaScript class directly or have to go over the model?

Comment: You can access the storage from anywhere in your application.

Comment: even in an xml class without having to parse it to a model? For Example in a direct usage in a Textview

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as an XML class. What you mean is a view. There you cannot access it because it's not a model. But you can use a formatter, which then accesses the storage. Or if your stored object is a model, you can bind that model to the view. But not the storage itself.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
this._oMyData =this._oStorage.get(syncTime);
```

will return nothing in your case, right? This is because you did not store a value before this call. Furthermore, I guess you should use a String for key...

Using SAPUI5 for accessing the localStorage would work like this:

```
// get an instance of  jQuery.sap.storage.Storage
var oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
//...

// Store
var syncTime = ...;
oStorage.put("syncTime", syncTime);

// Read 
var syncTime = oStorage.get("syncTime");
```

However, I prefer to use native JavaScript APIs, i.e. see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp:

```
// Store
var syncTime = ...;
localStorage.setItem("syncTime", syncTime);

// read
var syncTime = localStorage.getItem("syncTime");
```

The key should be string...